# React app fetch() response is empty although API endpoint returns data when sending a GET request from somewhere else

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, asp.net-web-api, fetch-api

This is what my API call looks like:

```
export async function getTasks(): Promise<Task[]> {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    return new Promise<Task[]>((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(DefaultTasksArray), 1500)
    );
  } else {
    return (await fetch("/api/tasks").then(
      (response) => response.json
    )) as unknown as Task[];
  }
}
```

GET action in the controller in the API

```
[HttpGet]
async public Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var tasks = await _service.GetAsync();

    return Ok(tasks);
}
```

The service in the API

```
private readonly IMongoCollection<TaskObject> _tasksCollection;

public TaskService(IOptions<TaskManagerDbSettings> taskManagerDbSettings)
{
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(taskManagerDbSettings.Value.ConnectionString);
    var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(taskManagerDbSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
    _tasksCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TaskObject>(taskManagerDbSettings.Value.TasksCollectionName);
}

async public Task<List<TaskObject>> GetAsync() =>
    await _tasksCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
```

When I send a GET request in Postman or in a browser, I get a JSON object like:

```
[
  {
    *data*
  },
  {
    *data*
  },
  ...
]
```

But the fetch() returns an empty response. What might be the cause?
I don't see any errors in the browser when I open the app.

upd:
I see the response in the Network tab in the browser, it has code 200 and all the data. But in the app itself the response is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it was actually caused by a small difference between the API output model and the UI response model. After I changed that, it's working as expected.

Also I shouldn't use "unknown as Task[]"
And yeah, response.json()

Answer (score 2):

The `json` property on the response from the fetch API is a function which you are mean to call.

```
(response) => response.json
```

should be

```
(response) => response.json()
```